# Looping through child elements with XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

Given the following xml (example) :

```
<root>
    <foo>some data</foo>
    <bar>some other data</bar>
</root>
```

I currently am reading it as :

```
reader.ReadToFollowing("root")
if(reader.HasAttributes) { /* not relevant in this usecase*/ }
while(reader.IsStartElement())
{
   reader.ReadStartElement()
   var elementName = reader.LocalName; 
   var value = reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(ExpectedType),null);
   //Process(elementName, value);
   reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```

If I run it like this, I got an exception

> 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType. on the reader.ReadEndElement();

If I remove that last line, the while is only executed once. foo is processed correctly, bar is not read.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would like to use the `ReadStartElement` and `ReadEndElement` methods here. Take a look to my code, the `Read` method advances the reader to the next element and returns true until you have more elements left in the XML document, so it does exactly what you're looking for.

```
        reader.ReadToFollowing("root");

        if (reader.HasAttributes) { /* not relevant in this usecase*/ }

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var elementName = reader.LocalName;
            var value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

            //Process(elementName, value);
        }
```

Comment: If I do it like that, I have to skip the WhitespaceNodes between the elements and I got "The ReadElementContentAs method is not supported on node type EndElement." on ReadElementContentAsString() on the second element...

Comment: Try skipping everything that's not an element, in the loop: `if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) { continue; }`

Comment: It seems like the ReadElementContentAsString() also positions the reader on the next element. Is it supposed to do so? If not, then I discovered a bug on the platform I am on (I am using a .Net CF clone on a smart device). Thx, it would explain a lot :-s

Comment: This is a supposed behavior, it works similarly on the standard .NET 4.5.